# Irq.h 82/26 syntax error in #if/#elif expression

Tags: c

I don't know very well the preprocessor conditionals and I get the following error :

```
Irq.h 82/26 syntax error in #if/#elif expression
```

On the following part of code :

```
#if (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ == 1U) //line 82

#ifndef IFX_INTERRUPT
#define IFX_INTERRUPT(isr, vectabNum, prio) \
                    void __interrupt(prio) __vector_table(vectabNum) isr(void)
#endif

#endif /* (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ == 1U) */
```

But I don't see/understand what's wrong...

Do you have any idea of where this issue could come from ?

Comment: What is `_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ `?

Comment: Line 82 is this one : #if (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ == 1U)

Comment: most likely _TASKING_C_TRICORE is not defined.

Comment: _TASKING_C_TRICORE is well defined in one of the *.c files : #define _TASKING_C_TRICORE_ (1U)

Comment: This definition has to be visible by this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you don't have `_TASKING_C_TRICORE_` defined so it can't evaluate that expression.  Try something like this;

```
#if defined (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_)
#if (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ == 1U) //line 82

#ifndef IFX_INTERRUPT
#define IFX_INTERRUPT(isr, vectabNum, prio) \
                    void __interrupt(prio) __vector_table(vectabNum) isr(void)
#endif

#endif /* (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_ == 1U) */
#endif /* defined(_TASKING_C_TRICORE_) */
```

Comment: error is always there despite the #if defined (_TASKING_C_TRICORE_)

Comment: Because it's not `TASKING_C_TRICORE` but `_TASKING_C_TRICORE_` ?

Comment: What is your compiler? Try with some other define and comparison. Maybe it is just not supported.

Comment: The compiler is "Tasking"

Comment: I've used the "Tasking" compiler before for some Conextant DSP work.  It builds in multiple stages and can be buggy.  Try a clean build maybe?

Comment: Even after a cleanall and then a build, the error is still there